# How to make this dropdown appear above the text below it

Tags: html, css, z-index

I've got a div which has another div drop down below it, but the drop-down appears below the content that's below it, and I want it to appear above it.

I've tried using `z-index` by setting a lower `z-index` for the content than the drop-down, but it's not working.

How can I make these divs appear in the correct order? - I've made a mockup of it on a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lexy0202/mvRYR/).

Comment: Z-index needs a position declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mvRYR/1/

You need to set `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;` when using `z-index`.

Answer (score 1):

just add

```
z-index: 10; position: relative;
```

to your `#drop` style

if you add `background-color: yellow;` as well, you could see it better...